# ElasticSearch sort a field in a result based on the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch data model like this:

```
  {
    "_index": "index_name",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "26177",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "primary_name": "Megatron Industries",
      "some_value": "",
      "search_names": [
        "Optimus",
        "Prime",
        "Lorem"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Currently I'm performing a query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "lorem",
            "fields"  : ["search_names"]
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm querying the documents based on the values in search_names.

On a website if someone conducts a search for a record with the name 'lorem', I would return this record showing their 'primary name', and then a list of their search_names labelled 'also known as'.

My issue is, a small number of these records have 1000+ 'search_names', so I'm going to have to cap the number of 'search_names' shown, but I want to ensure that the 'search_name' that's closest to their query is shown at the top of 'also known as'.

To clarify, I'm happy with the order of the search results, but I'm looking to then sort the value of one of the fields on a search result based on the query.

Is this something that I can do in ElasticSearch?

As a secondary goal, once that's sorted, any way I can then cap the number of results returned in the search_names field to say 10, but also provide another field that includes the total count as a number?

So I would then be able to show in the search results:

- Primary Name: Megatron Industries
- Also known as:  Optimus, prime, ... and 990 other names.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution to this was pretty simple. 
I just needed to add a highlight to the search_names field. ElasticSearch will automatically sort and highlight the field based on the query match. 
I was able to cap the results by setting the number_of_fragments in the highlight. 
Then I just excluded the original field from the result. 
Query below.

```
{
    "_source": {
        "excludes": [ "search_names" ]
    },
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Lorem ipsum",
            "fields"  : ["search_names"]
        }
    },
    "highlight": {
        "fields": {
            "search_names": { 
                "fragment_size" : 1000,
                "no_match_size" : 1000,
                "number_of_fragments" : 10,
                "pre_tags" : ["<b>"],
                "post_tags" : ["</b>"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```